# Strange multiple definitions error with headers

Tags: c++, multiple-definition-error

I have a strange multiple definitions error in my project.
I'm using the `#ifndef` preprocessor command to avoid including the same file multiple times. I cleared all other code. Here are my simplified files:

**1 - main.cpp**

```
#include "IP.hpp"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

**2 - IP.cpp**

```
#include "IP.hpp"

//some codes!
```

**3 - IP.hpp**

```
#ifndef IP_HPP_INCLUDED
#define IP_HPP_INCLUDED

unsigned char LUTColor[2];

#endif // IP_HPP_INCLUDED
```

Using codeblocks & gnu gcc in win7, it says:

> obj\Debug\main.o:C:\Users\aaa\Documents\prg\ct3\main.cpp|4|first defined here|
>
> ||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|

Before I deleted all of the other code, the error was:

> ||=== edgetest, Debug ===|
>
> obj\Debug\IP.o||In function `Z9getHSVLUTPA256_A256_12colorSpace3b':|
>
> c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\include\c++\exception|62|multiple definition of `LUTColor'|
>
> obj\Debug\main.o:C:\Users\aaa\Documents\prg\edgetest\main.cpp|31|first defined here|
>
> ||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|

And 'LUTColor' is in IP.hpp !

What's wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Repeated Multiple Definition Errors from including same header in multiple cpps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223771/repeated-multiple-definition-errors-from-including-same-header-in-multiple-cpps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the header - you need:

```
#ifndef IP_HPP_INCLUDED
#define IP_HPP_INCLUDED

extern unsigned char LUTColor[2]; // Declare the variable

#endif // IP_HPP_INCLUDED
```

- Do not define variables in headers!

You also need to nominate a source file to define `LUTColor` (IP.cpp is the obvious place).

See also: [What are extern variables in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c), most of which applies to C++ as well as C.

Comment: _Do not define variables in headers!_ unless they are const! +1

Comment: Are things that are `const` considered to be _variable_?

Comment: const bool myBad_IsNotVariable = true;

Comment: But the point that constants are allowed in headers is worth making, and I didn't make any distinction between variables and constants, so your comment adds some value.  Thanks.